# Simple Donation's donation amounts display incorrectly

Tags: wordpress, extension, contribution-page, donations, simple-donate-form

I just installed the extension Simple Donate to try it out.  When I view the donation page generated it looks like this, with lots of decimal points on the donation amounts (my normal donation page has no decimal points).  I can't see where I would control this - anyone know?

[image: Simple Donation page]

This is what I see when I inspect:
[image]

Comment: Have you checked to see if your Theme might be involved by changing to a really simple template (stating your CMS might help if that is the case)

Comment: Sorry, should have stated we're using 4.7.29 on Wordpress 4.9.2.

Comment: I'm really novice with using Inspector - see original post to see what I see if I inspect one of the buttons.

Comment: I did had this issue - when creating a membership price set - Civi was adding multiple zero's after decimal point - Easiest would be to change in CMS - Else try updating to 4.7.31 - that might help

Comment: I see the same problem as Ruth with Simple Donate (from Github master), CiviCRM 5.1.0, Joomla 3.8.7, and any template. The amount buttons on the page look like Ruth's screenshot, and if I 'inspect element' the extra decimal places are visible in the html, same as for Ruth.

Comment: Is there a fix for this? I am on CiviCRM 5.1.2 and it still does not seem to be resolved. Drupal 7.59.

Comment: I am still waiting for a fix on this myself.

Comment: @SohalKhatwani and Ruth D, I posted a fix for it here: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24933/zero-s-after-the-decimal-in-simple-donate