# zero s after the decimal in simple donate

Tags: contribution-page, simple-donate-form

Hi  I am using CiviCrm 5 on wordpress,

donation amounts displayed with zeros floating points after the decimal for example 25.00000000 instead of 25

Is there any solution?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Adding a link for the extension https://civicrm.org/extensions/simple-donate

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24556/simple-donations-donation-amounts-display-incorrectly but no solution

Comment: I am having the same problem. All those zeros are in the Price Set - Price Options configurations for Option Amount. The problem appears to be that Simple Donate is showing the Option Amounts, not the Option Label, like it is supposed to. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5np0q.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5np0q.jpg) [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6iFh.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6iFh.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer**: I've prepared a patch that I'd love for someone to test to fix this.

**Longer answer**: In recent months, CiviCRM has implemented support for currencies with more than two digits after the decimal point.  This is important both for cryptocurrencies as well as certain countries' tax calculations.  The decision was, "Store all currencies in the database with nine significant digits, and when displaying them, format them according to the rules of that currency."

This all happened in CiviCRM core and it went so well that end users who didn't need the greater accuracy didn't notice.  Unfortunately, no one updated Simple Donate.

I don't use Simple Donate, but recently handled a similar problem in my custom code, so I looked and it was a 4 line fix.

I'd love for someone affected by this problem to test my patched version and report back if you have any problems with it.  If there are no issues, I'll submit the patch to the original authors. I'd especially love feedback from users who don't use US dollars as their currency!

Find the fix on [my Github repo](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/com.webaccessglobal.simpledonate/tree/sig-digit-fix) or [download directly](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/com.webaccessglobal.simpledonate/archive/sig-digit-fix.zip).  When unzipping, please be sure to rename the folder to match your old extension folder name that you're replacing.

Comment: As an additional comment - I noticed that no one had informed the original authors of the problem.  The extension has a "Support" URL when you're in the extensions menu, but there are no tickets reporting this issue.

Comment: But  shouldn't the extension be reading the Label field for the buttons and not the Amount field? I actually created an account on civicrm.com so I could report the problem the authors, but I haven't been able to log in.

Comment: @fdarn This extension isn't written by the CiviCRM core team, so they won't be able to help you.  I just posted a new question to show how to report a bug on an extension: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25746/how-can-i-report-a-bug-about-an-extension/25747#25747

Comment: I posted the issue with the extension's authors, but seeing how they have 9 other issues they haven't responded to in over a year, I am not encouraged.  So I take it nobody else uses Simple Donate.  Is there another similar extension or option?  Surely not everyone is using just the basic civi form?

Comment: @fdarn If you could test my fix and confirm it solves the problem, they're more likely to merge something already written than write their own fix.  As for whether it should be reading the label vs. the amount - I can't say.  This is how the extension was written, and have no thoughts as to whether it's the best way.  I think there's an argument that it would be hard to maintain the simple layout with arbitrary length labels, but I also see your argument that this is less flexible.

Comment: @fdarn To answer "what people use" - I most often use the basic Civi form, which can be styled quite extensively using CSS.  I also sometimes use CiviCRM-Webform integration on Drupal.  My understanding is that Caldera Forms on WordPress can also take payments now, though with limitations.

Comment: G  I am using your fix on my test site now. So far it seems much better.  I would prefer to show it as $10 in the buttons instead of $10.00 . Is there a line I could edit to do that?  I just finished installing it and taking the first look. So I can 't yet say there are no issues, but if you only made minimum changes to the original extension, it is probably good.

Comment: @fdarn I made an alternate version that drops zeroes when not necessary: https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/com.webaccessglobal.simpledonate/tree/sig-digit-fix-alt

Comment: G Thank you.  That did work.  It did remove the additional zeros as I wanted it to. However when I try to advance to the credit card information step, it is blank space with no form.  I am now convinced that Simple Donate and IATS cannot be used together.  Unless someone can confirm they are using it together, this is very disappointing.

Comment: @fdarn I recommend asking on https://chat.civicrm.org.  Simple Donate isn't very popular, but iATS is, so I'm guessing you'll find someone who can give feedback.