# How can I report a bug caused by an extension?

Tags: extension, issues, bug-reporting

CiviCRM.org has [a page on reporting bugs](https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting), but my bug is in an extension.  How should I report it?

Answer (score 3):

You must report it to the extension author.  The CiviCRM core team doesn't have any control over third parties who write extensions.

To find the author's preferred place to report a bug:

- Go to **Administer menu » System Settings » Extensions**.

  - It might be in **Administer menu » Customize Data and Screens » Manage Extensions** if you upgraded from an older version.
- Click the **triangle** to the left of the misbehaving extension (see screenshot below).
- Click on the *Support* link and submit your issues there.

[image]

Usually the link will be to an issue repository - possibly on Github, possibly on [the CiviCRM GitLab](https://lab.civicrm.org).  Occasionally it will be to Stack Exchange.

Some authors may only offer paid support.  Please remember that extension authors give their work away for free and treat them well!