# Number of zero after colon in Price field

Tags: price-sets

Is there a way to reduce the number of 0 after colon in a simple price field in the backend?

[image: i]

For example, this is what I see in Price Fields Window.[image]

I read [this post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24933/zero-s-after-the-decimal-in-simple-donate) and JonG's answer but I'm not working on a simple donation.

I use CiviCRM 5.19.3 on Drupal 7.67 and currency is euro.

Regards,

Guillaume

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you using? Can you show a larger screenshot that show which screen you're on?  What is your default currency?

Comment: I've edited my post

Comment: Is the server on windows? There's still some problems with 0's on windows, including that screen.

Comment: no it's debian or ubuntu one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The backend isn't exposed to the visitor, so you might just not worry about it.
2. There is a good reason to have currency showing to what might seem an excessive number of places: taxes! For example, a membership price on that screen would be showing the amount exclusive of taxes, and if you lived somewhere that typically shows prices with tax included, then you might want a membership price that makes use of those extra places.

Comment: thanks Alan, this makes sense. Our customer are mostly not-for-profit organization without tax duty but it could be in some way useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding %!.2n in 'Monetary Value Display' under localization settings(administer>> localization >> Languages, Currency, Locations)

Comment: it didn't bring any changes :-( thanks anyway Pradeep.